# How to improve the speed of scanning qr code in ZBarScannerView

Tags: android, android-camera, barcode-scanner, android-camera2

I am using ZBarScannerView for scanning barcode. But for scanning process it takes time to scan the barcode. SO is there any solution for fast scanning the barcode.Below is the code.

```
  private void scanQR() {
        isScanQr = true;
        startCamera();
        contentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        submitBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        collectionRadioGroup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        areaAutoComplete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        areaAutoComplete.setText("");
        idAutoComplete.clearFocus();
        idAutoComplete.setText("");
        idIpLayout.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.hp_gp_id_hint));
    }
 private void startCamera() {
    scannerView.startCamera();
}
```

On permission I have checked camera permission

```
 public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == AUtils.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA) {
        //check if all permissions are granted
        boolean allgranted = false;
        for (int grantResult : grantResults) {
            if (grantResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                allgranted = true;
            } else {
                allgranted = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (allgranted) {
            checkCameraPermission();
        } else if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) mContext, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

            AUtils.showPermissionDialog(mContext, "CAMERA", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, AUtils.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    } else if (requestCode == AUtils.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION) {
        //check if all permissions are granted
        boolean allgranted = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
            if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                allgranted = true;
            } else {
                allgranted = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (allgranted) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        } else if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            AUtils.showPermissionDialog(mContext, "Location Service", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, AUtils.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

The scanning part is not quick enough so what to to.I used this library
implementation('me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.9.13')

Comment: Please attach the code of what you have tried

Comment: Pls see the edited code

Comment: Try setting the barcode formats , to only few types of barcodes you need to scan 'void setFormats(List<BarcodeFormat> formats);'